# How bad of an idea is it In an emergency to use my PV solar and propane generator together?

Tags: ac, inverter, generator, solar-energy, home-installation

#### Set the stage:

Say there is a massive grid disruption like what happened to Puerto Rico after Hurricane Maria. I live somewhere were air conditioning may be needed for some groups to remain healthy.

I have a 7 kWh PV solar install and a 6kWh stand alone generator(Its on wheels).

Say to run my house with air conditioning: I need 10kWh of production and demand for air conditioning matches the solar cycle.

Without air conditioning the generator can handle everything.

#### My idea is:

I could throw the main breaker and for redundancy cut the utility tamper lock and pop off the meter to prevent back feeding to the grid. Then I could wire the 240 output of the generator in to the distribution panel alongside the 240 out of the solar.

The solar will not run when the grid is out. I assume it knows when the grid is out by the lack of a AC sine wave. So connecting the generator will give it a wave to match.

#### The real question:

From 0 - 10, where 1 is about as dangerous as an open flame indoors and 10 being might as well try it if you're going to die anyway, how bad of an idea is this? Why?

Comment: Generator has overcurrent and undercurrent protections. 

Also assume: I do this at night, have input disconnects, take proper precautions when doing the wiring, and have the appropriate safety equipment.

Comment: If you want safety, then don’t talk about bypassing the electrical supplier’s infrastructure. There are legal and safe methods to isolate yourself from the grid. Your solar and generator are rated in kW not kW/h. Given infinite fuel, your generator could generate way in excess of 7kW/h.

Comment: What you are proposing seems reasonable. However, please do it properly by installing a transfer switch between the utility meter and the panel.

Comment: @Kartman If the only objection is the disconnect method: I would of course throw the main breaker. The solar back feeds into the panel via a breaker. So throwing the main disconnect would create an island. I said pop off the meter was to show 100% I would not back feed onto the grid and create a safety issue for linemen. 

Actual solar system size is 8kW. Typical solar noon production is 7kWhs. So its very likely in any event I would make the 4 kWH difference or the over protection on the generator would trip and everything would shutdown.

Comment: @DwayneReid basically I would buy the transfer switch and the generator connector but not hook it up except in a real life or death emergency. My utility [wont let you install one of these](https://www.homedepot.com/p/GenerLink-30-Amp-Meter-Mounted-Transfer-Switch-MA23-N/301961623) and the manufacture don't recommend you use them with solar. Otherwise this would be trivial. Basically what I want to understand why this isn't a standard thing. They install solar all the time with batteries, almost never with transfer switches. Why?

Comment: @user2115867 Are transfer switches make before break? Because solar cells are basically diodes and semiconductors are delicate snowflakes that can be fried by something like a generator.

Comment: @DKNguyen Any generator over current would need to go through the inverter before it could mess with the solar panels. The inverter is presumably use to this because it happens everyday at night.

Comment: Do you know how an inverter works? You can send current backwards through one. An inverter is rather powerless against something across its output terminals actually supplying power rather than consuming it.

Comment: Install the transfer switch right now while you are hot on the idea. If grid power goes out, fire up the generator and throw the switch to select generator power. Once the solar comes on, turn on the AC. The only danger is if the solar inverter tries to put out more AC than the load needs. The generator cannot absorb power. Not sure what happens in that case (could be bad).

Comment: Nobody recommends running an inverter with a generator because generators cannot absorb power. Bad things could possibly happen. Maybe the generator will start to motor and over-drive the prime mover. Maybe the solar inverter will run the voltage up too high, then fault out and then run the voltage too high, then fault out, etc.

Comment: This is a grid tie inverter, right?

Comment: @mkeith doesn't this happen in an off grid solar setup when the batteries are full? How is a generator different? Wouldn't the generator just not see any pull and just idle?
Yes it is a grid tied inverter.

Comment: Not an EE comment, but won't a hurricane blow the solar panels away?

Comment: Off grid charge controllers are completely different from grid tie inverters. Grid tie inverters are designed to run from higher voltage strings. Off grid charge controllers are typically designed for nominal 48V or lower battery packs. There may be some newer systems that support battery storage and grid-tie. Those may be designed to allow islanding.

Comment: Grid tie inverters, especially older ones, have no notion of a grid that doesn't need power. They always try to dump as much power into the grid as they can. Generators can drop to zero output but not below zero. So that is why there is potential for trouble unless the load can always consume 100% of the inverter output.

Comment: You must synchronize the inverter to the generator. Same voltage , frequency and phase to load share with a sinusoid. Otherwise problems.

Comment: "Good" inverters have multiple inputs (one for solar panels, one for a generator / grid, one for wind ) and will combine the inputs as needed. Dedicated outputs for charging batteries as well as supply to load are also provided.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work. A grid-tied PV inverter will go into an overvoltage error as soon as it produces more then the load.

If it even accepts the unstable frequency to start operation to begin with.

You may even damage the generator since you may not have negative kw/kvar protection.

It can be done, but you need to limit the PV load. Last month our entire suburb was on a generator (approx 500 kVA) for a week. All PV systems remained operational because there was more load than peak PV watts.